# Is there a way to use a lambda expression to find non-null values in NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, lambda

The question pretty much says it all.  I have a NameValueCollection where all values start as null, and then are set to specific values as things move along.  Each time a value is set, I need to find the number of items in the collection where the value != null.  Currently I'm iterating through the collection and counting the non-null values, but I would like to find if there is a way to do it cleaner through a lambda expression.

Comment: would this help you? `Collection.Count((i) => i != null ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: You shouldn't be doing a linear search through the collection to count the items in the first place.  That's a particularly inefficient algorithm.  Why do you have a bunch of null entries in the first place?

Comment: `Each time a value is set / count the number of value!=null` - so why don't you cache the value? If you know the collection starts at 0, then 'each time a value is set', check what was set and either do +=1 or -=1 depending on whether the new value is null or not. This way, you will always have the "value!=null" statistics at hand and up-to-date, and you will not need to scan the whole collection each-time.

Comment: @Servy is right, but using @Icepickle's technique, you could just do `Collection.Count(x=>x != null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NameValueCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` but you can use `OfType` method with `Keys` property to turn keys into `IEnumerable<string>` and use `Count` method:

```
int nullCount = collection.Keys.OfType<string>().Count(x => collection[x] != null);
```

Comment: I am really curious who is downvoting all the answers and not providing reason... Anyways - OfType vs Cast - I think blind Cast would be more applicable, as we know all keys are always String. Tiny performance difference, but it'd be more of a semantic reminder. But of course, no big deal. I just felt compelled to rant about the downvotes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like:

```
NameValueCollection collection = ...; // init as appropriate

int countOfNull = collection.Cast<string>().Where(key => collection[key] != null).Count;
```

?

It's not really clear how you found yourself in this situation. It would be better if you could use a more appropriate data structure, such that knowing how many keys have been populated is naturally available as an immediate value (e.g. keep a counter alongside the collection, or only add the key/value pairs when there is a value, etc.)

Comment: I agree that the current collection type is inappropriate, but this is one of those cases where going back and changing it to a dictionary or something more appropriate is more effort than the inconvenience of the current situation.